# How to compute each cell of a line in an array with Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While importing from an excel file to a database, I need to format a hierarchy so it appears with leading zeros:

10.1.1.4 must be transformed into 1.010.001.001.004

I tried to iterate through and concatenate the elements:

```
  record.hierarchy = spreadsheet.cell(i,2).split('.').each do |t|
      index = index || '1.'
      index = index + '.' + (((t.to_i + 1000).to_s).last(3))
    end
```

which actually returns and array of ["10", "1", "1", "4"], not computed. I would expect this to return the last evaluated value: index

I tried to compute it directly inside the array:

```
  record.hierarchy = '1.' + (((spreadsheet.cell(i,2).split('.').each).to_i + 1000).to_s).last(3).join('.')
```

which raises an undefined method to_i for enumerator.

Can someone explain me how to structure and solve this computation?
Thanks

Comment: _"I would expect this to return the last evaluated value"_ – your expectation is wrong. [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-each) calls the given block but it returns its receiver, i.e. the array returned by `split('.')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [different function](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/rjust) for leading zeroes and inject to not set default value inside the loop

```
record.hierarchy = spreadsheet.cell(i,2).split('.').inject('1') do |result, t|
  result + '.' + t.rjust(3, '0')
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [#rjust](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-rjust).

`'10.1.1.4'.split('.').map { |l| l.rjust(3, '0') }.join('.')`

Your first solution uses assignment with `#each`. `#each` will not return modified array.

Comment: Should be `rjust(3, '0')` to match the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to convert the string to an array, modify the elements of the array and then join the array back into a string. The string can be modified directly using [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub).

```
str = '10.1.1.4'

('1.' + str).gsub(/(?<=\.)\d+/) { |s| sprintf("%03d", s.to_i) }
  #=> "1.010.001.001.004"
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format).

`(?<=\.)` is *positive lookbehind* that requires the matched digits to be preceded by a period. I've assumed the string is known to contain between one and three digits before and after each period.